# Oops left baby back ribs on warm instead of low for 7 hrs

Tags: slow-cooking, ribs

Would the meat still be ok to eat if I cooked it on low for another 8 hrs after being on warm for 7 hrs?

Comment: I really don't think that's a good choice for a duplicate. That question is asking about using the warm setting *after* cooking it, which is actually OK, as opposed to using the warm setting *instead* of cooking it, which is a hospital visit waiting to happen.

Comment: agreed this isn't a duplicate. leaving cooked food on warm is fine. uncertainties on leaving uncooked meat on warm - that's like letting raw meat sit out in the heat

Answer (score 2):

You have essentially incubated the food for 7 hours, positively encouraging growth from any existing fauna or pathogens.   You should definitely discard.

Answer (score 1):

While that will kill any remaining bacteria, it won't remove their waste products which have been produced up to that point.

Please ask yourself this question: is saving a little money worth the (high) risk of getting food poisoning?

Comment: Don't be so sure that it will even kill the remaining bacteria; posted cooking times are based on maximum levels of bacteria typically found in properly-stored foods; although they die at an exponential rate at high temperatures, they also grow at an exponential rate at warm temperatures. Bacterial toxins are probably the more dangerous risk, but after 7 whole hours of incubating I wouldn't be surprised if there were still an unsafe amount of bacteria left after cooking it. Some types are more heat-tolerant than others.